# Can We Convert set to map or map to set in salesforce?

Tags: apex, map, set

I am new to salesforce. I want to convert sets into maps or maps into sets. how can I convert this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Set and Map definition

A **Set** is an unordered collection of elements that do not contain any duplicates, while a **Map** is a collection of key-value pairs where each unique key maps to a single value.
Both Map and Set methods are all instance methods, so they all operate on a particular instance of a Map/Set.
**Beware**: A Set can hold `null` values and the same goes for Map keys.

### Map to Set

Map provides a [`keySet()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_keySet) method to get the set of all keys:

```java
Map<Id, Account> mapIdToAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Name, AccountNumber FROM Account LIMIT 10]);
// The following set holds every map's key
Set<Id> accountIds =  mapIdToAccount.keySet();
```

If you want to create a set from the map's values you have to iterate over them via [`values()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_values) method, which returns a list that contains all the values in the map.

```java
Map<Id, Account> mapIdToAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Name, AccountNumber FROM Account LIMIT 10]);
// The following set holds every AccountNumber of map's accounts
Set<String> accountNumbers = new Set<String>();
for (Account acc : mapIdToAccount.values()) {
    accountNumbers.add(acc.AccountNumber);
}
```

**Please note** that if you choose to store a not unique value in the set, its size will be lower that the map's one.

```java
Map<Id, Account> mapIdToAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Name, Industry FROM Account LIMIT 10]);
// The following set holds every AccountNumber of map's accounts
Set<String> industries = new Set<String>();
for (Account acc : mapIdToAccount.values()) {
    industries.add(acc.Industry);
}
// If there are at least two accounts with the same industry, the size of the set will be lower than the map's one.
System.debug(industries.size());
```

### Set to Map

In order to create a Map from a Set you should have a set of non primitive types, i.e. a set of Sobject, otherwise the key and the value of the map will be the same, therefore the map will be useless.

Set of SObject to Map

```java
Set<Account> accounts = new Set<Account>([SELECT Name, Industry FROM Account LIMIT 10]);
Map<Id, Account> mapIdToAccount = new Map<Id, Account>();
for (Account acc : accounts) {
    mapIdToAccount.put(acc.Id, acc);
}
```

**Keep in mind** that if you choose a not unique sobject's field as key, in order to not overwrite a record, the map should hold a list of sobject as value:

```java
Set<Account> accounts = new Set<Account>([SELECT Name, Industry FROM Account LIMIT 10]);
Map<String, List<Account>> mapIndustryToAccountList = new Map<String, List<Account>>();
for (Account acc : accounts) {
    List<Account> accountList = mapIndustryToAccountList.get(acc.Industry);
    if (accountList == null) {
        accountList = new List<Account>();
        mapIndustryToAccountList.put(acc.Industry, accountList);
    }
    accountList.add(acc);
}
```

Set of primitive (i.e. Integer) to Map

```java
Set<Integer> numbers = new Set<Integer>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Map<Integer, Integer> numbersMap = new Map<Integer, Integer>();
for (Integer i : numbers) {
    numbersMap.put(i, i);
}
```